# Automorphism groups of "reductive" Lie algebras in positive characteristic

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, positive-characteristic, modular-lie-algebras, restricted-lie-algebras

I put "reductive" in quotes because, of course, in positive characteristic one should speak of Lie algebras of reductive groups, not of reductive Lie algebras.

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a field $k$ of positive characteristic, which you can assume algebraically closed if it helps.  I am particularly interested in the characteristic-$2$ case.

Is the adjoint quotient $G/{\operatorname{Centre}(G)}$ the full connected automorphism group of $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$, EDITED TO ADD: *as a restricted Lie algebra*?  If not, then does this hold if $G$ is assumed already adjoint, or instead if $G$ is assumed simply connected?

I don't know much about representability results for automorphism-group schemes, so, to remove any such subtleties, let's take the question to mean:  if $H$ is a smooth, connected group that acts on $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$ (optionally with either of the specialising assumptions on $G$ above), EDITED TO ADD: *as a restricted Lie algebra*, then does the action map $H \times \operatorname{Lie}(G) \to \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ factor through a map $H \to G/{\operatorname{Centre}(G)}$, in the obvious sense?

If the answer to the question is "no", then I'd be interested in any description of the image of $G$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Lie}(G))$, including if necessary any subtleties about the description of the latter automorphism-group scheme.

Comment: "Steinberg, Robert; Automorphisms of classical Lie algebras. Pacific J. Math. 11 (1961), 1119–1129." describes the automorphism group of $Lie(G)$ when $G$ is simple.

Comment: @spin, thanks!  There are some restrictions in [that article](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424658/automorphism-groups-of-reductive-lie-algebras-in-positive-characteristic#comment1091610_424658), among them that, in characteristic $2$, it does not handle $A_1$ or non-simply-laced groups.  I am particularly interested in the characteristic-$2$ case.

Comment: What if $G$ is the multiplicative group?

Comment: @spin, after another look at [that article](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424658/automorphism-groups-of-reductive-lie-algebras-in-positive-characteristic#comment1091610_424658), I guess that 7.3 says that equality fails when $G$ is of type $A_2$ with $p = 2$ or $D_n$ with $n \ge 4$.  (I guess this comes from their exotic embeddings as "short root" groups.)  That seems to be an answer, so, if you'd like to post it, then I would accept it.

Comment: @JasonStarr, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1091613), I meant, but didn't explicitly say, that I wanted restricted-Lie-algebra automorphisms; I think that the Lie algebra of $G = \mathbb G_m$ has only $p$ of those, right?   But, anyway, @‍spin [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424658/automorphism-groups-of-reductive-lie-algebras-in-positive-characteristic#comment1091610_424658) that the result does not hold even in the positive-characteristic case.

Comment: On third read, I think that the paper @spin [mentions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424658/automorphism-groups-of-reductive-lie-algebras-in-positive-characteristic#comment1091610_424658) will only produce 'exotic' automorphisms of Lie algebras of non-simply connected types $A_2$ ($p = 3$—I misspoke when I said $p = 2$ earlier) and $D_n$ ($p = 2$).  This doesn't prove that the result is true once we restrict to $G$ simply connected, since there are plenty of cases that Steinberg doesn't consider when $p = 2$, but it also doesn't rule it out.